# SVN commit failing due to missing file

Tags: svn

My SVN won't commit:

```
mac:MiTokeniPhone anemployee$ svn commit .
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: '/Users/anemployee/Desktop/MiTokeniPhone/main_bg.png' is scheduled for addition, but is missing
```

I used:

`svn revert -R .`

Would there have been a way to avoid having to revert?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You didn't do a recursive revert or a revert on the file that is missing. You might consider doing a

```
svn revert /Users/anemployee/Desktop/MiTokeniPhone/main_bg.png
```

**EDIT:** Since the question was edited and the OP found the recursive revert:

You could just create the file ... or don't add it in the first place. Other than that it's simply something for SVN that it was told to do ("Add that file to version control and check it in") which seems impossible ("Which file? I know it was here yesterday ... aaaahh!"). Kinda like that.

Answer (score 11):

`main_bg.png` is deleted before it is committed to svn server.

You can delete it from local copy using `svn rm main_bg.png` if you do not want to add it to server.
After that, you can commit your local changes.

Or you need to create `main_bg.png` file again.

Answer (score 8):

You should reference the missing file explicitly:

```
svn revert main_bg.png
```

or

```
svn delete main_bg.png
```

Then do the commit again.

Answer (score 7):

```
svn revert -R Desktop/MiTokeniPhone/
```

to revert the folder or

```
svn revert main_bg.png
```

to revert the file